# Finding and adding to a .kml file using python

Tags: python, text, string-parsing

I am not a very good coder. But I really want to automate something I have to do at work. Basically, I have a bunch of placemarkers in google earth showing hand-holes of a municipal fiber network. I have a few pictures of each hand-hole that I want to place as a  tag in the .kml file. Basically, I want to have it so when they click on a placemarker in google earth, it brings up the little description bubble and shows the pictures for each hand-hole and probably some other vital info.

Right now I have each hand hole labeled as either TO-. So hand-hole number 101 has a TO-101. And I have already made a script that has renamed all the pictures to match the name. So, if hand hole TO-101 has 3 pictures, they would be TO-101-1.jpg, TO-101-2.jpg, TO-101-3.jpg.

So, basically, I am trying to make a python script that reads the kml file (which I have done succesfully). I need it to find the corresponding TO-101 or whichever handhole in the .kml file, add a line below that line that reads:

```
<description> <img src="TO-101-1.jpg"><img src="TO-101-2.jpg"></description>.
```

Need to do this for about 5000 pictures and 2000 or so hand-holes.

I have tried to this:

```
import string, glob, sys, os, fileinput
f = open('./hand-holes.kml','r')

while f:
line = f.readline()
if line == "<name>TO-101</name>":
print line
```

And I can't even get it to find and print that line. I know the line is in the file, and I know the path is right. Because if I comment out the if line == "TO-101" it displays the contents of the file. So, if I can't even get that to work, there is no chance I am going to get the rest of it to work. I have tried looking at several pieces of search and replace type python example code. Some of it uses a string library, which I am not sure if I need to use.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Renosis

Comment: This looks like a form of xml... If so parsing it with lxml might work.

Comment: There are Python modules out there for working with KML: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykml , http://www.kfilimon.com/knowledgebase/39-programming/61-kmlmodule.html , http://code.google.com/p/simplekml/

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer - It is xml... I really only know how to use python, basic (picaxe for robotics), some basic html. I first tried to learn some xml to do it, but some of the examples to modify xml docs were in java script, which I have very little grasp of. And I really didn't understand domxml or whatever. I have never heard of lxml. I'll look into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the reason your `if line == "<name>TO-101</name>"` line doesn't work is because it probably has whitespace preceding it. If you changed it to line.strip() == ... then it would presumably work.

Your best bet would be to implement an XML handler to read in the existing file, parse it, and add the new  section. Start maybe with [xml.sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html)

Comment: Starting with SAX is probably a bad idea. SAX is a lower-level system for writing XML parsers. For most needs, you're much better off using an existing parser like lxml.

Comment: Good to know! I was only familiar with `xml.sax` and `xml.dom`, which sometimes are tedious for simple tasks.