# Python, problems modifying a text file, searching for terms

Tags: python, text-parsing

I posted a question yesterday here: [Finding and adding to a .kml file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944708/finding-and-adding-to-a-kml-file-using-python)

I have read a bunch of tutorial and now have a better understanding of python and that is good. Yet I still can't seem to get my script right. I know I am so very close. Basically I want to add a bunch of jpg's to a .kml file, which is basically .xml in google earth. I want my program to find a google earth "placemarker" in the xml file called:
    TO-XXX

where XXX matches the TO-XXX.jpg. I already have a folder with a bunch of .jpgs whose filename matches the name of each placemarker. I need the program to find the

```
<name> (for example <name>TO-101</name>)
```

and add a line right below the name line with a:

```
<description> <img src=TO-101.jpg></description>.
```

So, I have the code written, but I just can't seem to get it to find the . Which is always written:

```
"\t\t\t<name>TO-XXX</name>\n".
```

So, here is the code:

```
import os

infile = 'TO-Hand-Holes2.kml' # the file I am reading
outfile = 'TO-Hand-Holes-Output.kml' # the file I plan to write to, using print for now
images = os.listdir("./images") # the images folder, all image names match names

source = open(infile, 'r')
target = open(outfile, 'w')

x = 0 #an incrementer
i = 0 # an incrementer

readxml = source.readline
while x < 20000:   #There are about 17,000 lines in the .kml file
    readxml = source.readline()
    while i < len(images):
        word = images[i]
        if readxml == "\t\t\t<name>%s</name>\n" % word[:6]: #!!!!!!!!! the problem is here
            print readxml #output the <name>
            print word[:6] #output the <description>
            hit = 'true'
            i = i + 1
        else:
            hit = 'false'
            #print "test%s" % word[:6]
            i = i + 1
    if hit == 'false':
        print ("%s") % readxml
    x = x + 1
```

I just can't seem to get it to recognize the  lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you ensure that the formatting / indentation that displays is what you're actually using?  If so, this shouldn't work really much at all.  Your first while loop doesn't have anything it executes (no indented block below it).  Additionally, if it is set up like above, you read the 20000 lines before you attempt to process any of them.

Comment: oops, it didn't paste right, the rest of the lines of code are actually indented to be under the while x < 20000 loop. Fixing!

Comment: When you say does not recognize, do you mean the match on `readxml == "\t\t\t<name>%s</name>\n" % word[:6]` does not work or there is no output? On the latter point, I do not see any place that you write to your output file. You need something like this: `print >> target, word[:6]`, assuming pre-python 3.0.

Comment: #hughdbrown Yes, that is exactly what I mean and I can't understand why. When looking at the source file, that is exactly how it is typed out. I have tried without the \n too. Right now I am just running in the command line and > to a file.

Comment: Also, FYI, this is Python 2.7

Comment: I would like to post my code for what I ended up doing. For reference I suppose. It seems like it is bad form to answer your own question though. And I don't want to modify the code up top obviously. Is this not something that is normally done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because indentation is syntax in python you *really* need to be careful about where things are located.  This may come closer.  It's not 100% complete, but it will point you in the right direction:

```
with open(infile) as fhi, open(outfile, 'w') as fho:
  for line in fhi:
    if line == 'myMatchString':
      fho.write(line.replace('this', 'that'))
```

That uses the multiple file syntax for the `with` statement, which was introduced in 2.7.  Prior to 2.7 you'll have to nest a second `with` to get the second file.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes but I don't have the files to test it on. I made some Python-related changes for your learning purposes. I think you should test if the info you want is in the string rather than checking for equivalence. If you want to check for equivalence, you should use line.strip() because it will contain tabs, newlines, etc that you might not be accounting for (and you don't want to explicitly account for, tbh).

```
import os

infile = 'TO-Hand-Holes2.kml' # the file I am reading
outfile = 'TO-Hand-Holes-Output.kml' # the file I plan to write to, using print for now
images = os.listdir("./images") # the images folder, all image names match names

source = open(infile, 'r')
target = open(outfile, 'w')

for line in source.readlines():   #read all of the source lines into a list and iterate over them
    for image in images:  #you can iterate over a list like this
        word = image[:6] #i moved the list slicing here so you only have to do it once
        if "<name>" in line and word in line: #!!!!!!!!! the problem is here
            print line #output the <name>
            print word #output the <description>
            hit = True  #use the built-in Python boolean type
        else:
            hit = False
            #print "test%s" % word[:6]
        target.write(line)
        if hit:
            target.write("<description> <img src={0}></description>\n".format(image)

source.close()
target.close()
```

Comment: Don't use `for line in source.readlines()`.  It reads the entire file into memory, which there is no reason for.  File Handles are their own iterables.  You should use `for line in source`.

Comment: OK.... I am trying this out. It seems to be reading the file. I am very confused now. hehe. Basically I need the source file to read exactly the same as the destination file, except with a<description><img src='./images/TO-XXX.jpg'></description> added below each line that has the <name>TO-XXX</name>. So, due to my lack of experience, I was certain the only way to do this is to read each line in the file, write each line, but if a <name>TO-XXX</name> appears, also write a <desciption><img src="TO-XXX.jpg"></description> as the next line and continue on.

Comment: And I know my code won't put the <description> tags in there yet. I was going to add that part in later after I confirmed that the search and add line part was working.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the part that writes the line...I edited it

Comment: Thanks Brandon and everyone for your help. I finally got it working out. I just didn't know enough to do what I wanted to do. After a weekend of doing many Python tutorials... I was able to add all the images to my placemarkers in one fell swoop. In the end, it probably would have been faster to just add them manually. But there is more data and pictures being gathered as I type this... so I will definitely reuse the script. And I will be able to add even more features. Found out that Google Earth has support for alot of cool things I can do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This would be better:

```
import os

infile = 'TO-Hand-Holes2.kml' # the file I am reading
outfile = 'TO-Hand-Holes-Output.kml' # the file I plan to write to, using print for now
images = os.listdir("./images") # the images folder, all image names match names


with open(infile, 'r') as source:
    with open(outfile, 'w') as target:
        for readxml in source:
            for word in images:
                hit = readxml == "\t\t\t<name>%s</name>\n" % word[:6]
                if hit: #!!!!!!!!! the problem is here
                    print readxml #output the <name>
                    print >> target, word[:6] #output the <description>
```